# Migration Plus entity_lookup fails

Tags: migrations

Drupal version: **8.7.1**.
Used modules:

- Migrate
- Migrate Plus
- Migrate Tools
- Migrate Spreadsheet

I'm trying to generate a taxonomy term if this does not already exist.
the migration file:

```
...
source:
  plugin: spreadsheet
  columns:
   ...
   - 'Functie'
   ...
process:
  ...
  field_function:
    plugin: entity_generate
    source: 'Functie'
    value_key: name
    ignore_case: true
    bundle: function
    entity_type: taxonomy_term
  ...
```

The taxonomy bundle name is **function** and the column in the spreadsheet
containing the values is **'Functie'**. However, I'm getting the following error:

> [error]  Error: Call to a member function getConfig() on null
> in
> Drupal\migrate_plus\Plugin\migrate\process\EntityLookup->determineLookupProperties() (line 217 of
> /var/www/html/web/modules/contrib/migrate_plus/src/Plugin/migrate/process/EntityLookup.php)
>
> /var/www/html/web/modules/contrib/migrate_plus/src/Plugin/migrate/process/EntityLookup.php(182):
> Drupal\migrate_plus\Plugin\migrate\process\EntityLookup->determineLookupProperties('field_function')
>
> /var/www/html/web/modules/contrib/migrate_plus/src/Plugin/migrate/process/EntityGenerate.php(116):
> Drupal\migrate_plus\Plugin\migrate\process\EntityLookup->transform('Medewerker',
> Object(Drupal\migrate_tools\MigrateExecutable),
> Object(Drupal\migrate\Row), 'field_function')
>
> /var/www/html/web/core/modules/migrate/src/MigrateExecutable.php(394):
> Drupal\migrate_plus\Plugin\migrate\process\EntityGenerate->transform('Medewerker',
> Object(Drupal\migrate_tools\MigrateExecutable),
> Object(Drupal\migrate\Row), 'field_function')
>
> /var/www/html/web/core/modules/migrate/src/MigrateExecutable.php(203):
> Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutable->processRow(Object(Drupal\migrate\Row))
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/includes/drush.inc(223): Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutable->import()
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/includes/drush.inc(214): drush_call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> /var/www/html/web/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/Commands/MigrateToolsCommands.php(766):
> drush_op(Array)
>
> [internal function]: Drupal\migrate_tools\Commands\MigrateToolsCommands->executeMigration(Object(Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration),
> 'profiles', Array)
>
> /var/www/html/web/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/Commands/MigrateToolsCommands.php(321):
> array_walk(Array, Array, Array)
>
> [internal function]: Drupal\migrate_tools\Commands\MigrateToolsCommands->import('profiles',
> Array)
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(257):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(212):
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->runCommandCallback(Array,
> Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(178):
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->validateRunAndAlter(Array,
> Array, Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php(302):
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->process(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput),
> Array, Array, Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255):
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->execute(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(978): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(255): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand), Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(118):
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(49): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun(Array,
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(72): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run(Array)
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(18): require('/var/www/html/v...')
>
> phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/bin/drush.php(141): drush_main()
> /usr/local/bin/drush(10): require('phar:///usr/loc...')

If anyone could point out what's going wrong, by all means, enlighten me because I have no clue what's going on, the configuration seems right to me.

Comment: This doesn't lool like a valid YML, leading whitespaces are very importtant in YML. You need to intend `- 'Functie'` to the proper level

Comment: Yeah my bad, edited the yaml in this post. this is how it looks like in my file.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but try explicitly listing the bundle_key below `field_function`: `bundle_key: vid`

Comment: Oh yeah, that fixed it for me! Thanks a bunch @Hudri!

Answer (score 0):

You need to explode your source - I used a comma in this case. You then need to generate against the specific vid you want to import into:

Try something like this:

```
fields:
-
  name: name_i_gave_this_field
  label: 'Taxonomy Term I want to Import'
  selector: termname
process: 
  field_my_entity_reference_to_taxonomy:
 -
  plugin: explode
  source: name_i_gave_this_field
  delimiter: ','
-
  plugin: entity_generate
  lookupBundleKey: vid
  lookupBundle: my_vocabulary_name
```

Make sure that your Taxonomy Term reference field allows you to create content.

Comment: Isn't explode only used when you have multiple values in one cell ? Also, it doesn't seem like i'm able to use the fields since I'm using the spreadsheet plugin. I've only started with migrations since a few days ago so I'm not sure tho'.

Comment: Sorry, that was my presumption that you might have more than one value. Simply set the first source to:  

    plugin: default_value
    source: name_i_gave_this_field